# Best solution to Deploy docker with volumes

Tags: docker, docker-volume

I am new to Docker. I have created a docker image with Java, Node , Git config etc and deployed locally with 3 Volumes and I can see that running perfectly fine in Docker Desktop.

I am not able to find proper solution anywhere how to deploy Docker with volumes.

Can anyone help me doing that?

Or there is only one solution to have EC2 instance in AWS or same sort in any other cloud platform and run docker in same way I am doing in local system?

Please Help.
Thanks.

**Command Used** - docker run -d --name CONTAINER_NAME --mount source=android-app,target=/app/android-app --mount source=keystores,target=/app/keystores --mount source=app-icons,target=/app/app-icons -p 5000:5000 DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME_WITH_TAG

Comment: What specific problem are you having?  Is it a question about building your application, or configuring your EC2 instance?  Docker-on-EC2 isn't especially different from Docker on a local native-Linux system (you have other choices like EKS managed Kubernetes or Amazon's proprietary ECS system as well).

Comment: The problem is i am not able to deploy docker in kubernetes engine or Google registry container with volumes. I have some data which I fetch from git and have to maintain that in volume